# TypeError: 'Image' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
def main():
    **P= Image.open("C:\Users\Yona\.spyder-py3\1.PNG")**
    P_1 = P.convert('RGB')
    WIDTH = 80
    HEIGHT = 80
    P_2 = P_1.resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

    txt = ''

    for j in range(HEIGHT):
        for i in range(WIDTH):
            txt = txt+get_char(*P_2.getpixel(P_2(j,i)))
            txt = txt+ '\n'

    print(txt)
```

Why PIL Image.open is not callable?
how do I call this function?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the Image.open line is the line causing the error? Because I'm suspicious of that line farther down, with the `P_2(j,i)`...

Comment: Please edit the full traceback for the error into the question.

Comment: `"C:\Users\Yona\.spyder-py3\1.PNG"` this path isn't valid unless you use raw strings: `r"C:\Users\Yona\.spyder-py3\1.PNG"`